# Remove duplicate domains from list with regular expressions

Tags: regex, string, text, uri

I'd like to use PCRE to take a list of URI's and distill it.

**Start**:

```
http://abcd.tld/products/widget1       
http://abcd.tld/products/widget2    
http://abcd.tld/products/review    
http://1234.tld/
```

**Finish**:

```
http://abcd.tld/products/widget1
http://1234.tld/
```

Any ideas, dear members of StackOverflow?

Comment: What language are you using? Does this have to be entirely with regex or can other language features be used?

Comment: how do you decide the uniqueness? why is widget2 and "review" not included?

Comment: I'm using TextMate currently, but could use any language necessary to do the task. The list is quite large.

Comment: I only need one URI from each domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can you simple tools like [uniq](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq).

See kobi's example in the comments:

```
grep -o "^[^/]*//[^/]*/" urls.txt | sort | uniq
```

Comment: This should do it (top domains only): `grep -o "^[^/]*//[^/]*/" urls.txt | sort | uniq`

Comment: @Kobi: That strips out the URI's, but is definitely much better than what I've come up with since I posted the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While it's INSANELY inefficient, it can be done...

```
(?<!^http://\2/.*?$.*)^(http://(.*?)/.*?$)
```

Please don't use this

Comment: Important to mention: the list must be sorted (=URLs with identical domains must be listed in one group).

Answer (score 1):

Parse out the domain using a URI library, then insert it into a hash. You'll write over any URL that exists in that hash already so you'll end up with unique links.

Here's a Ruby example:

```
require 'uri'

unique_links = {}

links.each do |l|
  u = URI.parse(l)
  unique_links[u.host] = l
end

unique_links.values # returns an Array of the unique links
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can work with the whole file as a single string, rather than line-by-line, then why shouldn't something like this work. (I'm not sure about the char ranges.)

```
s!(\w+://[a-zA-Z0-9.]+/\S+/)([^ /]+)\n(\1[^ /]+\n)+!\1\2!
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have (g)awk on your system

```
awk -F"/" '{
 s=$1
 for(i=2;i<NF;i++){ s=s"/"$i }
 if( !(s in a) ){ a[s]=$NF }
}
END{
    for(i in a) print i"/"a[i]
} ' file
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
http://abcd.tld/products/widget1
http://1234.tld/
```