# Regular Expression in gVim to Remove Duplicate Domains from a List

Tags: windows, regex, vim

I need a regular expression written to use in gVim that will remove duplicate domains from a list of URLs (gVim can be downloaded here: http://www.vim.org/download.php

I have a list of over 6,000,000 URLs in a .txt file (which opens in gVim for editing).

The URLs are in this format:

```
http://www.example.com/some-url.php
http://example2.com/another_url.html
http://example3.com/
http://www.example4.com/anotherURL.htm
http://www.example.com/some-url2.htm
http://example.com/some-url3.html
http://www.example2.com/somethingelse.php
http://example5.com
```

In other words, there is no specific format to the URLs. Some have the WWW, some don't, they all have different formats.

I need a regular expression written for gVim that will remove all duplicate DOMAINs from the list (and it's corresponding URL), leaving behind the first instance it finds.

So it would take the example list posted above, and the end result should look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/some-url.php
http://example2.com/another_url.html
http://example3.com/
http://www.example4.com/anotherURL.htm
http://example5.com
```

Here are two nice sites that explain how to use regular expressions within gVim pretty nicely:

http://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/documentation/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/gvim/gvim.html#Vi-Regular-Expressions

http://www.softpanorama.org/Editors/Vimorama/vim_regular_expressions.shtml

Comment: Can you show us some examples of what you've tried so far?  One trick for finding/removing duplicates that I've found is to sort the list, first.  It's a huge file, so that might be a difficult option for you, but it might also make your regex much simpler.

Comment: gVim actually has a very nice feature built in for sorting the URLs, so that's no problem at all.  I simply type the following & press enter     :sort u  That sorts all the lines alphabetically, and then removes duplicate LINES (not domains).  As for showing some examples, I haven't gotten very far.  Here is one (that I got from this site actually, but gVim says that it isn't a recognized command or regular expression) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280666/remove-duplicate-domains-from-list-with-regular-expressions

Comment: according to gvim's documentation the format to enter what you're looking to do, should be in this format: :start_point,end_points/search_pattern/replacement_pattern/g  and this URL gives some simple examples http://147.188.192.43/documentation/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/gvim/gvim.html#Vi-Regular-Expressions ...but my knowledge of regex is nothing at all...until today, I hadn't even heard of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it using regular expression, you can try to adjust the following: `%s!\v%(^http://%(www\.)?(%([^./]+\.)+[^./]+)%(/.*)?$\_.{-})@<=^http://%(www\.)?\1%(/.*)?\n!!g`, but it is will be *very* slow on 6 billions of urls and does not work for unknown reason. Here is a better approach:

```
:let g:gotDomains={}
:%g/^/let curDomain=matchstr(getline('.'), '\v^http://%(www\.)?\zs[^/]+') | if !has_key(g:gotDomains, curDomain) | let g:gotDomains[curDomain]=1 | else | delete _ | endif
```

It is doing the following:

1. `let g:gotDomains={}` creates an empty dictionary where we will hold all domains
2. `%g/^/{command}` execute `{command}` on every line
3. `let curDomain=matchstr(...)` get domain name

   1. `getline('.')` from the current line
   2. `\v` allow me omit writing lots of backslashes in regex (very magic)
   3. `^` from start of string
   4. `\zs` start match from here (omit capturing everything before `\zs`)
4. `if !has_key(g:gotDomains, curDomain)` if domain has not occurred before.
5. `let g:gotDomains[curDomain]=1` then add it to the list of known domains (we do not need `1` here, I use dictionary only for faster access).
6. `delete _` else delete the line to *black hole* register (which means, do not save its contents in any registers).

Comment: WOW!  That second solution you provided (and then clearly explained WHY it was a solution) works perfectly!  Thank you so much ZyX!  I've spent A LOT of time looking for a solution, and that is spot on, exactly.  I truly appreciate you taking the time to not only provide the solution, but to then explain it...well, that is truly helpful.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Robert: this place is unbelievable. People help us with their time with so much insightful answers. Try to always upvote people here and thank then. I'm very grateful for the answers I got here!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
%! sort | uniq
```

Comment: To be completely honest, I'm not even sure HOW to try that, haha.  I appreciate the help though!